# How to avoid rows on screen when cutting spritesheet tiles?

Tags: 2d, javascript, tilemap, tiles

I'm having a problem with my spritesheet, I generate a map but when I zoom in on it I can observe these lines as in the image below:

[image]

When I used the tiles each in their separate image, that did not happen, how do I avoid this case?

I'm drawing like this, the problem happens when I give a "ctx.scale":

```
ctx.drawImage(
    imgSolos.img,
    (imgSolos.width * resultSolo), // resultSolo is current frame in the spritesheet
    0,
    32,
    32,
    x, 
    y,
    imgSolos.width,
    imgSolos.height
);
```

Comment: Please add more details about how you draw those tiles and how you implemented that zooming feature (browser-window zooming? css style of the canvas? context.scale?)

Comment: @Philipp I use ctx.scale to zoom in. I have edited the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keep in mind that context.scale does not change the internal resolution of the canvas. It just adds a multiplication factor to all coordinates you pass to the drawing functions. Due to [floating point inaccuracies](https://www.floating-point-gui.de/) on scale factors which are not factors of 2, those coordinates might no longer be pixel-perfect. The result is what you see in that screenshot.

Possible solutions are:

- Implement scaling by changing the width and height of the destination rectangle of your `drawImage` calls. Use the same number of pixels for the x- and y-increments in your map drawing loops. Use integers only.

  Note that this might still cause artifacts between the tiles because you will have blurring on each individual tile but no blurring across tile borders.
- Draw your map to a second, invisible canvas *without* scaling. Then draw that invisible canvas to the visible canvas *with* scaling. That way the whole map will get scaled as one image (this might seem inconvenient, but most 2d engines end up adding such an additional layer of indirection sooner or later for a variety of reasons)
- Use CSS to change the size of the canvas in the HTML document. The browser will then stretch the output of the canvas. This actually has the same effect as the previous method, but moves the implementation to the browser's rendering engine
- Only use scale factors which are either integers, or 1 divided by a powers of 2 (0.5, 0.25, 0.125...).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but how could I limit it to the power of 2? for example something that looks like this: `zoomCamX += 0.1;`

Comment: @PerduGames implement zoom-in and zoom-out as `zoomCamX *= 2.0` and `zoomCamX /= 2.0`.

Comment: but I can still see the lines. When it moves away I can no longer see the lines, but when I get closer I see them.

Comment: @PerduGames It works for me. Are you sure you start out with a scale factor of 1? When power-of-2 zooms are too fast for your game, then try one of the other 3 solutions I suggested.

Comment: Going back here, I could show an example javascript in how to do: "Draw your map to a second, invisible canvas without scaling..." I'm not sure if I'm looking right.

Comment: I tried doing this by creating an invisible Canvas to store the image, then I drew the invisible screen on my screen with the changed scale, and I get the same problem from the lines on the screen. It also happens when I use ".translate"